# How do you display options from an array in PowerShell when creating a ComboBox in XAML

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, azure-powershell

I am creating a wpf ui in powershell using xaml. I am attempting to fill my combo box with an array and whenever I load the window/combobox, no options appear for me to select from. I have tried a few methods to resolve this, including using the ItemsSource element in xaml scriptblock, using DisplayMemberPath inside and outside the xaml block, creating a function to help display the window and then passing the variables from inside the window to the scriptblock.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong - any and all help is appreciated.

```
Do {
    Connect-AzAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $AzureAccount = Get-AzContext
    $CurrentAccount = $AzureAccount.Account.Id
    $CurrentAccount
} While ([String]$AzureAccount::isnullorempty)

Do {
    # Select Subscription
    Try {
        $azureSubscription = (Get-AzSubscription | Sort-Object Name | Out-GridView -Title "Choose your Azure subscription and click OK." -PassThru)
        Write-host "Switching to Azure subscription: $($azureSubscription.Name)"  -ForegroundColor Green;
        $azureSubscriptionInfo = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $azureSubscription.Id
    } Catch {
        Write-Output "Script Terminated"
    }
    # Select Location
    Try {
        $azureLocation = (Get-AzLocation | Sort-Object Name | Out-GridView -Title "Chosose your Azure location and click OK." -PassThru)
        Write-Host "Switching to Azure location: $($azureLocation.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Green
    } Catch {
        Write-Output "Script Terminated"
    }
    if ([String]$azureSubscription::isnullorempty) {
        $Primary = "False"
    } elseif ([String]$azureLocation::isnullorempty) {
        $Primary = "False"
    } 
} while ($Primary -eq "False")

# Get Virtual Networks and associated Subnets
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$vnetList = @()
$subnetsList = @()
foreach ($vn in $vnet) {
    if ($vnet.Location -eq $azureLocation.Location) { 
        $vnetList += $vnet.Name 
        $subnetsList += $vnet.Subnets.Name }
}
$vnetList = $vnetList | Where-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Unique
$subnetsList = $subnetsList | Where-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Unique

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Virtual Machine Deployment Tool" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <ComboBox x:Name="vnselect" Margin="5" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

$vnselect = $window.FindName("vnselect")
foreach ($item in $vnetList) {
    $vnselect.Items.Add($item)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see any items if you set the `ItemsSource` to `$vnet`?

Comment: yes, I tried this earlier by defining ItemsSource through xaml but wpf will split 1 item into individual letters. please see the image: https://imgur.com/a/3Xqtkiq

Comment: So `Get-AzVirtualNetwork`returns a `string`? You need to convert it to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Get-AzVirtualNetwork returns a set of variables from which I extract the name of each vnet which is then stored in an array. I've looked online for documentation in converting the name to an IEnumerable<string> using powershell but cannot find anything - any useful links?

Answer (score 0):

The code that added the items to the ComboBox should be placed before `$window.Showdialog()`. That's the resolution.